# Inherit attributes from another object in css

Tags: css

I have a class in my css called .btn:

```
.btn {
    //stuff here
}
```

and I am going to create another class, lets say .btn2. I want to be able to inherit the characteristics from .btn into btn2, as I only want to change the color of button 2. Is there a way in CSS for this? Or should I just copy and paste the original stuff into the new class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
/* comma-separated selectors: */
.btn,
.btn2 {
    /* shared properties */
}

.btn2 {
    /* properties unique to btn2 */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/34cVx/).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with dynamic stylesheets. Check out LESS or SASS.

EDIT:

Some additional info at a commenter's request. Here are the official sites. They both have examples on their home pages.

http://lesscss.org/
http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is this

```
.btn, .btn2 {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

This way, both the classes will share common properties defined in the rule block.

As far as the inheritance goes, something you would like to have..

```
.btn2 {
   .btn; /* Won't work in pure CSS */
}
```

Won't work in pure CSS, you need to take a look at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)